# MacOS Mojave and Dark Theme - Preview for .png file with transparent background not white

Tags: safari, preview, dark-mode

Not surprisingly at all, with MacOS Mojave and Dark Theme OS Mode, Preview displays transparent background with gray. How can I set it to be white only for preview but keeping MacOS Dark Mode ?

[image]

File opened with Safari which is perfect:

[image]

Comment: i'm so perplexed that this is not a bigger topic! All previews of transparent PNGs, specifically data plots, are ruined with this?? Did you figure out a way?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye, didn't figure out any way since then...

Comment: Have the same issue. Very frustrating.

Answer (score -1):

The is to change the default coulor scheme for your dark mode in preview.

[MacOS Mojave and Dark Theme - Preview for .png file with transparent background not white](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361985/macos-mojave-and-dark-theme-preview-for-png-file-with-transparent-background)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you elaborate on how to change the default color in Preview? The link you provide in your answer simply links to the question.